# Moving mirrored object problem

Tags: transforms, mirror-modifier

When i use mirror modifier i can't move, scale and rotate the object correctly. It moves only the inner coordination system of the object for the Z axes and it only moves the half of the object(the mirrored doesn't move at all) only at the X axes. I had the same problem before- it rotates not the whole object and then i applied the modifier and it started rotating correctly. Then i need to scale the object and it move the coordination's system only as now and then i just extrude it in edit mode, so i don't understand how to fix the actual problem.
My transform properties aren't locked. The origin point is at the center of the object, the 3d cursor too.
Don't know what's the problem and is it from the modifier but I have it when I use it.
The first one is the situation, the second when moving with G- it move only at X axes, the third is top view when moving
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: Or provide your blend file...

Comment: i edit the post,because i cant find if i can add a picture as a comment. I can't find how to attach file too.

Comment: i forgot to tag you both so @moonboots

Comment: @Chris and you, thanks both of you for responding

Comment: as Chris says, the blend file would be even better as I don't really get what you mean...

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com and follow instructions

Comment: You say that the origin pont is at the centre of the object. If you're using the mirror modifier it should be set to the 3D Cursor (assuming that's in the centre as it seems to be in your image). In Object mode, right-click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.

Comment: @Chris i upload it. I really don't know what's the problem. Maybe it's me

Comment: @JohnEason i did it, but it still moves only the half part of the object when i tried. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncheck orignis here -> than it works as expected again.

[image]

i am pretty sure you did what i did too often when i was bloody beginner: you searched for a shortcut and just typed it in - until you found it. Problem is: nearly every key combination does something in Blender. So i just can recommend: do only use shortcuts if you are sure you know them. So you will avoid a lot of trouble - which i had ;)

Comment: thank you soo much. I can't believe it works and i can go back to learning the program.

Comment: You are welcome